# Javafx I want to remove the dynamic element in Accordion

Tags: javafx, dynamic, removechild

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ts0m.png)

Question : How can I remove the element that I right clicked on? Example : World Pane2 Click And World Pane2 Remove.

Below is the code to dynamically create an element as I click the button.
Button Click:

```
 AnchorPane newPanelContent = new AnchorPane();
    VBox h = new VBox(10);
    h.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    newPanelContent.getChildren().add(h);
    h.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello World"));
    h.getChildren().add(new Button("Click"));
    TitledPane pane = new TitledPane("World Pane"+i, newPanelContent);
    System.out.println(accordion);
    accordion.getPanes().add(pane);
```

**Answer found.**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42988381/6306993

> ```
> pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
>     if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton())) {
>         accordion.getPanes().remove(pane);
>     }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a titled pane from an accordion when you right click on the titled pane:

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton())) {
        accordion.getPanes().remove(pane);
    }
});
```

Where `pane` is a reference to a titled pane.

*Full Sample App*

[image: sample app]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PaneRemoval extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        accordion.getPanes().addAll(
                IntStream.range(0, 5)
                        .mapToObj(this::createTitledPane)
                        .toArray(TitledPane[]::new)
        );

        StackPane root = new StackPane(accordion);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TitledPane createTitledPane(int i) {
        Pane content = new Pane();
        content.setPrefSize(100, 100);
        content.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk;");

        TitledPane pane = new TitledPane(i + "", content);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton())) {
                accordion.getPanes().remove(pane);
            }
        });

        return pane;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your reply worked. He's working in a healthy way right now.

Comment: The system does not allow me to give you points. Thank you again very much.